# Drupal 8 extensible module development approach

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am old Drupal developer and stopped at drupal 6 and now I am starting my studies of drupal 8 modules development.

I am porting a module to drupal 8 and this module that can be extended. The currently approach is using hooks and works well.

I want to know is hooks still the best approach or using the new OOP structure with services and dependency injection. (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection)

Thanks in advance,

Pedro Faria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [plugin API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/plugin-api-overview) for Drupal 8 is probably what you want

Comment: That's was exactly what I need... Thanks so much!